# How to make available all the memory allocated to a Gnome Boxes virtual machine?

Tags: gnome-boxes

I have Windows 10 running inside Gnome Boxes. When I created the virtual machine I allocated it 8 GM of RAM. When I run Windows' Task Manager:

[image]

It does recognize the 8 GB, but the VM only seems to be using 2.0 GB--and it feels like it, running sluggishly. System Monitor says there's 6 GB that are "hardware reserved." [This question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1437505/virtual-machine-doesnt-use-all-ram-allocated-to-it) was similar, though I'm running 22.04 rather than 20.04.

What do I need to do for all 8096 MB of memory to be available to the VM?